# how to attach url link to an image?

Tags: html, image, url, hyperlink

I am creating an website. It contains videos of different places. Now my problem is i need integrate an image on that with url link. when user taps on that link it has to go to that link. Even user downloads the video also it has to go to that link (same link above linked to image).

Comment: Accept this answer. It is corrent and there is no other answer to confuse you

Comment: Users of Stack Overflow would be more willing to help you if you accept questions that you find helpful. There is a checkmark under the score and vote buttons.

Comment: Six other questions and no accepted answers. It seems unlikely that there weren't any acceptable answers on any of them...

Comment: This user wants help all the time and doesn't even pay the users back with any votes, accepted answers or even feedback if anyone helped... Very selfish person.

Answer (score 60):

> "How to attach url link to an image?"

You do it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/></a>
```

See it in [action](http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/1921726.html).

Comment: don't forget to set the border of the image to 0, otherwise some browsers may add a nasty blue border around it.

Comment: you're right, but I didn't want to go into styling considerations already

Comment: dns issues :/ should be fixed

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```
<style type="text/css">
#example {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url(../images/example.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
</style>

<a href="http://www.example.com" id="example">See an example!</a>
```

More wordy, but it may benefit SEO, and it will look like nice simple text with CSS disabled.

Comment: Hey alex, is there a way to add an image to a link without using a placeholder text??