# Add a link in a div tag

Tags: html, hyperlink

Good morning,

In HTML, I am trying to insert an image which should be clickable to open a link. Unfortunately, when I click on the image, nothing really happens. I am doing that in a 'div' tab, hoping that it is the correct way to achieve this.

```
<div id="nav">      
    <a href="http://www.20minutes.ch">
        <img src="assets/icons/icon_weather_forecast.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
    </a>
<img src="assets/icons/icon_worldwide_weather.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
<img src="assets/icons/icon_train_schedule.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
<img src="assets/icons/icon_useful_numbers.png" alt ="" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
</div>
```

Any idea why it does not work?

Many thanks for your hints and best wishes,
Laurent

Comment: Works perfectly in google chrome, mozzila and IE.  Try opening some page from system. Slow internet connection also can take time open page.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Please Refer This... This May Help You... `http://stackoverflow.com/a/1921735/2845151`

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSBin, or any similar tool, you'll see how your code works perfectly. Have you tried to use different browsers? Also you could try removing the id from the div to see if you have any CSS rule or JS that interrupts the anchor action.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. I found the problem which was in my css.

My tag did not mention : 
    position: relative;

Adding this line solved the problem. Again, many thanks for your efforts.